# What is the default number of workers in a dask compute?

Tags: python, dask

```
@delayed
def do_something():
    # Does some work
    pass

futures = [do_something() for x in range(100)]
compute(*futures)
```

does the default number of workers depend on our cpu cores? or does it run all the 100 in parallel (i assume this is not the case)

but how does it make a default worker count?

Comment: You can explicitly set the number of workers using `num_workers` in `compute`

Comment: nah, i want to know what is the default (just curiosity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [dask website](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html#configuring-the-schedulers) it defaults, as you suggest, to the number of cores.

Comment: "number of cores" as far as you can tell from python, which is often actually the number of virtual threads